# How can we convert 01-01-2011 19:00 to weekdays like Mon ,Tue .. in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I was working on a pandas dataframe where I had a column of datetime now I haveto convert it into Weekdays.How can I do this?

Comment: Agarwal Consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 6):

There is a datetime module you may want to use.

[strptime and strftime](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strftime.htm) methods from [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module:

```
In [1]: import datetime
In [4]: datetime.datetime.strptime('01-01-2011 19:00','%d-%m-%Y %H:%M').strftime('%A')
Out[4]: 'Saturday'
```

Comment: Ahh nice one! Parse the date, then unparse it again :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `datetime.strftime()` to parse the date then use `datetime.weekday()` to get the weekday as an integer:

**Example:**

```
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.strptime("01-01-2011 19:00", "%d-%m-%Y %H:%S")
d.weekday()  # 5
```

Now if we look at the documentation for [`datetime.weekday()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday) we can see:

> `date.weekday()`
>
> Return the day of the week as an integer, where
>   Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6.
>
> For example, date(2002, 12, 4).weekday() == 2, a Wednesday.
>
> See also isoweekday().

So knowing this we can write a simple function:

```
weekdays = {
    0: "Monday",
    1: "Tuesday",
    2: "Wednesday",
    3: "Thursday",
    4: "Friday",
    5: "Saturday",
    6: "Sunday",
}

def weekday(dt):
    return weekdays[dt.weekday()]
```

Now we can simply call `weekday()` on a given `datetime()` object instance:

```
d = datetime.strftime(">>> d = datetime.strptime("01-01-2011 19:00", "%d-%m-%Y %H:%S")
weekday(d)  # Saturday
```