# Numpy date time conversion

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion

I have a dataset that I have converted into a NumPy dataset. The dataset contains a series of date stamps.

A sample value would be: `2014-03-01 09:00:00`.

What I am wondering is if someone knows how to convert a NumPy datetime to the day of the week for example in this case it is Saturday.

Comment: You would need to show how you are convert to numpy dataset?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392710/how-can-we-convert-01-01-2011-1900-to-weekdays-like-mon-tue-in-python/30392970#30392970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is what your array looks like. If so, here's an example of how to do this.

```
import numpy, datetime
a=numpy.array([datetime.datetime.now(),datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(days=2)])
a[0].weekday()
```

The return value of `weekday` is *day of the week as an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6* according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html). You could also use `isoweekday` to get numbers from 1 to 7. So all you need now is, say, a dictionary like this: `daysOfWeek={0:'Monday',1:'Tuesday'}` etc. to get the names of the days of week instead of numbers.

Comment: Sorry, I am not looking for an array. What I want to know is what day of the week a given NumPy date falls on e.g. Mon, Tue, Wed.

Comment: Just use `weekday` on it. I've created an array just to serve as an example.